# Clarification required regarding Arrays, Vectors and Maps in usage of a C++ Application

Tags: c++, regex, dictionary, vector, io

I want to know the right algorithm and a container class for my application. I am trying to build one Client-Server communication system where the Server contains group of files (.txt). The file structure (prototype) is like:

`A|B|C|D....|Z$(some integer value)#(some integer value)`. Again the contents of `A to Z` are `a1_a2_a3_a4......aN|b1_b2_b3_b4......bN|......|z1_z2_z3_z4.....zN`. So what I wanted to do is when Server application has started, it has to load these files one-by-one and save the contents of each file in a Container class and again the contents of the file into particular variables based on the delimiters i.e.

```
for (int i=0; i< (Number of files); i++) 
{
1) Load the file[0] in Container class[0];
2) Read the Container class[0] search for occurences of delimiters "_" and "|"
3) Till next "|" occurs, save the value occurred at "_" to an array or variable (save it in a buffer)
4) Do this till the file length completes or reaches EOF
5) Next read the second file, save it in Container class[1] and follow the steps as in 2),3) and 4)
}
```

I want to know if `Vector` or `Map` suits my requirement? As I need to search for occurrences of delimiters and `push_back` them and access while necessity comes.

Can I read whole single file as block and manipulate with the buffer or while file read only using `seekg` I can push the values to stack? One which will be better and easier to implement? What are the possibilities of using `regex`?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kQnCS.png

Comment: I think your problem relates more to file *parsing* than data structures. You might want to read up on that. Also, in your case, you should definitely read all of a file (or a large chunk of it, if it's too large) and then work on that; do **not** seek back and forth in a file for parsing! (It will be excruciatingly slow.)

Comment: For parsing, you can definitely use regular expressions; however, if your values (Ai, Bj, ...) are numbers (integers of real values) you can use plain old `sscanf` (or even `scanf`) to read them and the separators.

Comment: @yzt Hmm, well its a combination of strings and integers... `sscanf` equivalent in C++ is `stringstream` I guess?

Comment: @highlander141: Yes. Either `scanf` family of functions, which are callable from C++ too, or `stringstream` and its ilk.

Comment: @highlander141: Could you say how large each of these files are? A couple of kilobytes? Tens of kilobytes? Megabytes?

Comment: @yzt It will be around `30KB` per file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the format of input, and its size, I'd suggest doing something along these lines for reading and parsing the input:

```
void ParseOneFile (std::istream & inp)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> data;
    int some_int_1 = 0, some_int_2 = 0;

    std::string temp;

    data.push_back ({});
    while (0 == 0)
    {
        int c = inp.get();

        if ('$' == c)
        {
            data.back().emplace_back (std::move(temp));
            break;
        }
        else if ('|' == c)
        {
            data.back().emplace_back (std::move(temp));
            data.push_back ({});
        }
        else if ('_' == c)
            data.back().emplace_back (std::move(temp));
        else
            temp += char(c);
    }

    char sharp;
    inp >> some_int_1 >> sharp >> some_int_2;
    assert ('#' == sharp);

    // Here, you have your data and your two integers...
}
```

The above function does not return the information it extracts, so you will want to change that. But it does read one of your files into a vector of vector of strings called `data` and two integers (`some_int_1` and `some_int_2`.) It uses C++11 and does this reading and parsing quite efficiently, both in terms of processing and memory.

And, the above code does *not* check for any errors and inconsistent formatting in the input file.

Now, for your data structure problem. Since I have no idea about the nature of your data, I can't say for sure. All I can say is that a two-dimensional array and two integers on the side feels like a natural fit for this data. Since you have several files, you can store them all in another dimension of vector (or perhaps in a `map`, mapping a file name to a data structure like the following:

```
struct OneFile
{
    vector<vector<string>> data;
    int i1, i2;
};

vector<OneFile> all_files;
// or...
// map<string, OneFile> all_files;
```

The above function would fill one instance of the `OneFile` struct above.

As an example, `all_files[0].data[0][0]` will be a string referring to data item *A0* in the first file, and `all_files[7].data[25][3]` will be another string referring to data item *Z3* in the 8th file.

Comment: By the way, the above code is confirmation of how useful C++11 is, even in trivial day-to-day code!